# DllNotFoundException, but DLL is there

Tags: c#, dllnotfoundexception

So I'm using an SDK for a hardware random number generator which provides a dll called PsyREG.dll for interacting with it, as well as some c# source for using the methods from the dll.

It has worked in the past, but somehow it has stopped working. My hands are a bit tied as I don't actually have access to the device in question at the moment, so I can't try a lot of things...

However, here's the weird thing. The dll is there, the same place it's always been. Ahd in fact `File.Exists("PsyREG.dll")` returns `true`, and I've double checked and that's the exact same way the provided c# source imports it, e.g. `[DllImport("PsyREG.dll")]`.

Any ideas?

Comment: I had a similar issue with Google OrTools. I found a fix here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63677664/1136310

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Probably this DLL has some dependencies that aren't registered or aren't in the same folder as your application.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. There were some other things that were needed, but for a few reasons I didn't think to check that (including the fact that it said it couldn't load PsyREG.dll, not a different file)

Comment: Times like this are when I break out Reflector.  It can show you the dependencies.  In particular, it can show you which ones aren't found.

Comment: Really? Does Reflector find unmanaged dependencies? Where is that option?

Comment: I use DependancyWalker and, if that fails (i.e., if the DLL is being loaded dynamically), FileMon to simply watch where searches fail.

Answer (score 9):

Open DLL on the problematic system in http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: This app did the job for me.

Comment: cool...that tool helped me resolve a lot of install problems when deploying.

Comment: No idea... Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977298/dependency-walker-equivalent-for-linux

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem and solved with the following:

There's a dependency on msvcr90.dll if you compile under /MD.
Try compiling the code with /MT instead.

`Project properties` > `C/C++` > `Code Generation` > `Runtime Library: /MT`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should check to see if you're expecting a specific product version of the dll, and make sure that the product versions still match up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with the same exception with regards to one of my DLL's (let's call it `A`). C# was crashing because it claimed it couldn't find this DLL (`A`) (while it was there in the same folder as the executable).

Turned out that the issue was caused by `A` having dependency on another DLL (call it `B`). `B` was not in the path so `A` couldn't load it when it needed it. Since `B` needed a whole bunch of other DLL's, the solution was to add `B`'s directory to the `PATH` environment variable.

It's interesting how C# crashes with the error saying that `A` is not found when in fact `B` was not found...

Comment: Can you explain the `the solution was to add B's directory to the path environment variable` part a little?
I'm currently struggeling with almost the same problem, only difference is that my Dll wants some *.so files instead of other Dll's.

Comment: @Stefan I believe in Linux terminal you would do `export PATH=$PATH:YOUR-SO-FILE-PATH` to add the directory `YOUR-SO-FILE-PATH` to your PATH environment variable. This way, when your `so` file needs to be loaded, the path specified by PATH will be searched to find that `so` file.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it that way but it didn't really work. I read somewhere else to move my dll into the `/usr/lib` directory (yes, it's indeed a linux system) and that worked without any further configuration