# Dependency Walker equivalent for Linux?

Tags: linux, unix, shared-libraries, dependency-walker

I need a tool to show all the shared library dependencies in some graphical way, not just  with `ldd` on each `.so`.  For MS Windows *[Dependency Walker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Walker)* works.  Is there anything for Linux?

[image: Dependency Walker example screen].

Comment: `nm` lists direct and indirect dependencies, but not in tree-format. Alternatively, someone wrote [a perl script](http://www.redhat.com/archives/rhl-list/2007-May/msg01670.html) that parses the ldd output for indirect dependencies.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try [binscan](http://sourceforge.net/projects/binscan/) or [ELF Library Viewer](http://www.purinchu.net/software/elflibviewer.php)