# How to make the program dynamic-library-linked being portable?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

this is my solution:

I move the program to another computer without any lib installed, read the error messeges and copy the lib one by one.

I have to repeat it several time until all library required is cpoied. In some cases, I don't know where is the lib neither do find it.

Is there any way make it easier?

Comment: The runtime libraries from Visual Studio already exists as an installable package (do a search for "redistributable runtime"). Also use something like [Dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find what other DLLs might need copying.

Comment: is there any solution in linux?

Comment: You want you solution in Linux? I tagged you post with linux too, approve the edit.

Comment: For Linux, it's usually not a good idea to just copy the libraries. Instead install the packages the libraries are a part of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). It is a free utility that scans EXEs and DLLs, and builds a hierarchical tree diagram of all dependent modules.

**Edit:**
On linux [try binscan or ELF Library Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977298/dependency-walker-equivalent-for-linux) (from SO answer by J-16 SDiZ).

Comment: what's the solution in Linux?

Comment: @snowcakeandicejelly [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977298/dependency-walker-equivalent-for-linux) is an answer on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I find that ldd and nm in binscan's page is enough for me

Answer (score -1):

Use a package management system.  They will differ depending on the flavor of linux, but just copying a binary from one machine to another is *not* the way to install software on a box.  If you want to get /bin/foo from machine A, to machine B, figure out which package /bin/foo belongs to on A and then install that package on B.  Downloading and installing all the dependencies should be as simple as:

```
$ aptitude install foo   # debian and debian derivatives
```

or

```
$ yum install foo        # rpm based distributions
```