# Error with z3.dll

Tags: c#, dll, z3

I try to use Z3 Prover for a university project in C# but when I start to create a Context Object I get this Error:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: Die DLL "z3.dll": Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden. (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x8007007E) kann nicht geladen werden.

   bei Microsoft.Z3.Native.LIB.Z3_del_context(IntPtr a0)

   bei Microsoft.Z3.Context.Finalize()

   bei Microsoft.Z3.Native.LIB.Z3_del_context(IntPtr a0)

   bei Microsoft.Z3.Context.Finalize()
```

Is here anyone, who knows a solution?

Thankyou!

Comment: Can you  provide the code that is creating the Context?

http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: private Context ctx = new Context();

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio Enterprise 2015

Comment: Created a litte chat room here:

http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129228/error-with-z3-dll

Comment: I can't char there because i does not have 20 reputation :/

Comment: Damn - I didnt want to flood the comments with questions. I was going to ask (just checking) - do you have a reference to the Z3 DLL for your project?

Comment: Yes I have. I also tried to change the x64 and x86 DLLs

Comment: ok, a quick search on SO here - some people are finding that there could de dependencies to the Z3.dll - i.e. you may need those DLLs as well within your bin directory.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246486/dllnotfoundexception-but-dll-is-there

Comment: Yes, I also tried this bevore also in the x64 and x86 Edition but it has no influence on the error.

Answer (score 1):

To use Z3 in .NET projects you need to have a reference to Microsoft.Z3.dll, which has a (native) dependency on libz3.dll. So, both DLLs must be accessible at runtime; e.g., by putting the directory that contains them into your PATH environment variable.

Also, make sure that the proper version is available, i.e., for 32-bit programs you have to use 32-bit DLLs, otherwise you will get error messages that don't help at all (e.g. it will simply report "can't load DLL").

Comment: Could you give me a example how to add a PATH environment variable? I would be very grateful :-)

Comment: On Windows: set PATH=%PATH%;c:\mypath

Comment: For more information consult the internet :-) E.g., here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable