# Trying to connect a ergometer to pc using a SDK but program can't find dll

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll, sdk

I'm trying to connect the *concept2* ergometer with a *PM4* with a computer so I can use it's input in a game made in *Unity3D*.

The company of the ergometer provides a [SDK](http://www.concept2.com/service/software/software-development-kit) that's in **C++** (I don't have experience with **C++**).

I'm using [this](https://micrological.appspot.com/article/content.projects.erg) code to wrap the **C++** code in **C#**. 
Here I replace "*RPPM3DDI.dll*" with "*PM3DDICP.dll*" and "*RPPM3Csafe.dll*" with "*PM3Csafe.dll*".

When I run the code the program throws the following exception:

> System.DllNotFoundExeption for DLL PM3DDICP.dll

I put the files of the SDK in the solution folder so that's not it I guess... 
So I read (on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246486/dllnotfoundexception-but-dll-is-there))  that there can be problems with the dependencies and I used *DependencyWalker*. 
 I got a ton of messages of missing dependencies but it turns out that *DependencyWalker* is not being maintained and some changes in *Windows* are causing the missing dependency reports...

The goal is to get the speed that a person is rowing with and use it in *Unity3d*.

The questions now are:

- **How can I use this SDK when he can't find the dll file?**
- **How can I locate the dependency issues among all the 'fake' missing dependencies?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and I thought: maybe this answer is usefull for someone else too.

The problem was that I put the SDK files in the wrong folder (noob mistake I know...).
I needed to put the files in: *Project folder* -> *bin* -> *Debug*

I couldn't find this solution on the internet