# Or Tools Sat Example not working within C# forms app

Tags: c#, or-tools

I have been able to run an example version of the scheduling program from GitHub.
However, as soon as I run it in Windows forms, I get the following error:

> System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for
>   'Google.OrTools.Util.operations_research_utilPINVOKE' threw an
>   exception.' DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL
>   'google-ortools-native': The specified module could not be found.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

I have tried on another PC with a new install of the package.

Comment: Looks like you're missing the DLL identified in the error message.

Comment: Can you make sure visual studio 2019 redistributables are installed ?

Answer (score 3):

As Laurent mentioned, you need to have Visual C++ Redistributables installed:

https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/VC_redist.x64.exe

(mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/optimization/install/dotnet/windows))

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error even I installed the c++ redistributable. In Visual Studio . I also had to install google or native runtime and add manually add the google-ortools-native.dll to the start-up project and mark it copy to output directory always. This was true for version 7.8 and 9.1.9. After that the error disappears.